# Calculate evaluation metrics using cross_val_predict sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

In the `sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_predict` [page](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_predict.html) it is stated:

> Generate cross-validated estimates for each input data point. It is
>   not appropriate to pass these predictions into an evaluation metric.

Can someone explain what does it mean? If this gives estimate of Y (y prediction) for every Y (true Y), why can't I calculate metrics such as RMSE or coefficient of determination using these results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be based on how samples are grouped and predicted. From the [user guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#obtaining-predictions-by-cross-validation) linked in the `cross_val_predict` docs:

> Warning Note on inappropriate usage of cross_val_predict
>
> The result of
>   cross_val_predict may be different from those obtained using
>   cross_val_score as the elements are grouped in different ways. The
>   function cross_val_score takes an average over cross-validation folds,
>   whereas cross_val_predict simply returns the labels (or probabilities)
>   from several distinct models undistinguished. Thus, cross_val_predict
>   is not an appropriate measure of generalisation error.

The `cross_val_score` seems to say that it averages across *all* of the folds, while the `cross_val_predict` groups individual folds and distinct models but not all and therefore it won't necessarily generalize as well. For example, using the sample code from the sklearn page:

```
from sklearn import datasets, linear_model
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict, cross_val_score
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, make_scorer
diabetes = datasets.load_diabetes()
X = diabetes.data[:200]
y = diabetes.target[:200]
lasso = linear_model.Lasso()
y_pred = cross_val_predict(lasso, X, y, cv=3)

print("Cross Val Prediction score:{}".format(mean_squared_error(y,y_pred)))

print("Cross Val Score:{}".format(np.mean(cross_val_score(lasso, X, y, cv=3, scoring = make_scorer(mean_squared_error)))))

Cross Val Prediction score:3993.771257795029
Cross Val Score:3997.1789145156217
```

Comment: I read it, but I'm not sure I fully understand.. this is why I posted this question in the first place, if some one can explain it in different words. Is it because each fold is based on a bit different model (e.g., different PCs in PCA), and therefore, calculating for example RMSE is not current because it will be based on predictions from slightly different models?

Comment: See my edits above. Without digging into the sklearn source code (which you can do on [github](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py)), you can view the results as shown. The differences are slight, but noticeable

Comment: Thank you, this was I thought, and your answer helped to confirm it.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a little more clarity, it is easier to understand the difference if you consider a non-linear scoring function such as Maximum-Absolute-Error  instead of something like a mean-absolute error.

cross_val_score() would compute the maximum-absolute-error on each off the 3-folds (assuming 3 fold cross-validator) and report the aggregate (say mean?) over 3 such scores.  That is, something like mean of (a, b, c) where a , b, c are the max-abs-errors for the 3 folds respectively.  I guess it is safe to conclude the returned value as the max-absolute-error of your estimator in the average or general case.

with cross_val_predict() you would get 3-sets of predictions corresponding to 3-folds and taking the maximum-absolute-error over the aggregate (concatenation)  of these 3-sets of predictions is certainly not the same as above. Even if the predicted values are identical in both the scenarios, what you end up with here is max of (a, b,c ). Also, max(a,b,c) would be an unreasonable and overly pessimistic characterization of the max-absolute-error score of your model.

Comment: Do you know if the sets of folds and indexes returned by cross_val_predict match those returned by the various K-Fold methods? If they do, one could calculate the same result as cross_val_score does.